# Slow Down Refresh Rate Of Bound DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datagrid, refresh

I've got a DataGrid in my WPF/C# app that is bound to an Entity Framework collection.  Each row has bound columns that change very frequently - many times per second.  This causes the column to basically be unreadable because it changes so often.  How can I force WPF to only show a new value every .5 seconds or 1 second even if the value changes every .1 second?

e.g.

```
dataGrid.MaxRefreshRate = 1000; (value in milliseconds).
```

Comment: Since this question is tagged WPF, I assume you mean DataGrid? DataGridView is Windows Forms. Also, does the Columns or the Collection change to fast?

Comment: @Meleak - Yes, sorry I meant the DataGrid in WPF.  The collection changes quickly, which in turn means that the DataGrid updates too frequently from INotifyPropertyChanged events.  I would just like the DataGrid to basically ignore some of the property changed events and just update, say, once a second.

Comment: Don't you allow the user to update the data in the datagrid? To confirm otherwise synchronizations issues will need to be addressed with this delayed update.

Comment: @bjoshi - Actually, I don't need TwoWay enabled, just OneWay from the DataSource to the DataGrid.  Hopefully, this simplifies it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to create a layer between your data and the datagrid.

Let's assume your data is of type List< Record > and at the moment it's bound to your DataGrid.

We'll need some wrapper class for your data (for one row in this case). This wrapper deffers property changed and fires it regularly. Notice: I wrote this code by heart without any testing, there might (and will) be bugs. It is also not thread-safe, you need to add some locks when working with the list. But the point should be hit.

```
public class LazyRecord : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  private string name;
  public string Name
  {
    get { return name; }
    set
    {
      if (name != value)
      {
         name = value;
         OnPropertyChanged("Name");
      }
    }

    // other properties

    // now the important stuff - deffering the update
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
       if (this.changedProperties.Find(propertyName) == null)
        this.changedProperties.Add(propertyName);
    }

    private readonly List<string> changedProperties = new List<string>();

    // and the timer that refreshes the data
    private readonly Timer timer;
    private readonly Record record;

    public LazyRecord(Record record)
    {
       this.timer = new Timer(1000, OnTimer);
       this.record = record;

       this.record.OnPropertyChanged += (o, a) => this.OnPropertyChanged(a.PropertyName);
    }

    public void OnTimer(..some unused args...)
    {
       if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
       {
        foreach(string propNAme in changedProperties)
        {
           PropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
        }
    }
}
```

After this, just create a List< LazyRecord > from your List< Record > and use that as your datasource. Obviously it is straightforward to use a generic solution, which is much more reusable. Hope I helped a little.

Comment: Thanks for the example and notes.  I think this will work nicely.

Answer (score 1):

Just an Idea how it could work.

- Have a shadow copy of your data bound to the gui element instead of binding the original data.
- Add an eventhandler that update the shadow-copy with a certain delay from the original data.

May be you find more and better answers on a similar newer question [how-to-do-the-processing-and-keep-gui-refreshed-using-databinding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4522583/how-to-do-the-processing-and-keep-gui-refreshed-using-databinding/4531428#4531428)

Comment: Thanks for the ideas and the link.  One of the answers on the link seemed helpful enough and generic enough to reuse.  Of course, it still seems like a common enough problem that I wish there was something built into DataGrid.

Answer (score -1):

Try `listView.Items.Refresh();`.

Comment: Well, I don't want to force a refresh.  In fact, I want to cancel some refreshes if they're too close to the last refresh.  I did find dataGridView.Items.DeferRefresh() but I'm not sure how to use it or if it's even the right way to do this.  I was trying:

using(dataGridView.Items.DeferRefresh())
{
  Thread.Sleep(500);
}