# How to do the processing and keep GUI refreshed using databinding?

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, data-binding

### History of the problem

This is continuation of my previous question

[How to start a thread to keep GUI refreshed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4497115/how-to-start-a-thread-to-keep-gui-refreshed)

but since Jon shed new light on the problem, I would have to completely rewrite original question, which would make that topic unreadable. So, new, very specific question.

### The problem

Two pieces:

- CPU hungry heavy-weight processing as a library (back-end)
- WPF GUI with databinding which serves as monitor for the processing (front-end)

Current situation -- library sends so many notifications about data changes that despite it works within its own thread it completely jams WPF data binding mechanism, and in result not only monitoring the data does not work (it is not refreshed) but entire GUI is frozen while processing the data.

The aim -- well-designed, polished way to keep GUI up to date -- I am not saying it should display the data immediately (it can skip some changes even), but it cannot freeze while doing computation.

### Example

This is simplified example, but it shows the problem.

XAML part:

```
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <Button Click="Button_Click">Start</Button>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Counter}"/>
    </StackPanel>
```

C# part (please NOTE this is one piece code, but there are two sections of it):

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window,INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    // GUI part
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var thread = new Thread(doProcessing);
        thread.IsBackground = true;
        thread.Start();
    }

    // this is non-GUI part -- do not mess with GUI here
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void OnPropertyChanged(string property_name)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property_name));
    }

    long counter;
    public long Counter
    {
        get { return counter; }
        set
        {
            if (counter != value)
            {
                counter = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Counter");
            }
        }
    }


    void doProcessing()
    {
        var tmp = 10000.0;

        for (Counter = 0; Counter < 10000000; ++Counter)
        {
            if (Counter % 2 == 0)
                tmp = Math.Sqrt(tmp);
            else
                tmp = Math.Pow(tmp, 2.0);
        }
    }
}
```

### Known workarounds

(Please do not repost them as answers)

I sorted the list according how much I like the workaround, i.e. how much work it requires, limitations of it, etc.

1. this is mine, it is ugly, but simplicity of it kills -- before sending notification freeze a thread -- Thread.Sleep(1) -- to let the potential receiver "breathe" -- it works, it is minimalistic, it is ugly though, and it ALWAYS slows down computation even if no GUI is there
2. based on Jon idea -- give up with data binding **COMPLETELY** (one widget with databinding is enough for jamming), and instead check from time to time data and update the GUI manually -- well, I didn't learn WPF just to give up with it now ;-)
3. Thomas idea -- insert proxy between library and frontend which would receiver all notifications from the library, and pass **some** of them to WPF, like for example every second -- the downside is you have to duplicate all objects that send notifications
4. based on Jon idea - pass GUI dispatcher to library and use it for sending notifications -- why it is ugly? because it could be no GUI at all

My current "solution" is adding Sleep in the main loop. The slowdown is negligible, but it is enough for WPF to be refreshed (so it is even better than sleeping before each notification).

I am all ears for real solutions, not some tricks.

**Remarks**

*Remark on giving up with databinding -- for me the design of it is broken, in WPF you have single channel of communication, you cannot bind directly to the source of the change. The databinding filters the source based on name (string!). This requires some computation even if you use some clever structure to keep all the strings.*

Edit: *Remark on abstractions -- call me old timer, but I started learning computer convinced, that computers should help humans. Repetitive tasks are domain of computers, not humans. No matter how you call it -- MVVM, abstractions, interface, single inheritance, if you write the same code, over and over, and you don't have way to automatize the things you do, you use broken tool. So for example lambdas are great (less work for me) but single inheritance is not (more work for me), data binding (as an idea) is great (less work) but the need of proxy layer for **EVERY** library I bind to is broken idea because it requires a lot of work.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my WPF applications I don't send the property change directly from the model to the GUI. It always goes via a proxy (ViewModel).

The property change events are put in a queue which is read from the GUI thread on a timer.

Don't understand how that can be so much more work. You just need another listener for your model's propertychange event.

Create a ViewModel class with a "Model" property which is your current datacontext. Change the databindings to "Model.Property" and add some code to hook up the events.

It looks something like this:

```
public MyModel Model { get; private set; }

public MyViewModel() {
    Model = new MyModel();
    Model.PropertyChanged += (s,e) => SomethingChangedInModel(e.PropertyName);
}

private HashSet<string> _propertyChanges = new HashSet<string>();

public void SomethingChangedInModel(string propertyName) {
    lock (_propertyChanges) {
        if (_propertyChanges.Count == 0)
            _timer.Start();
        _propertyChanges.Add(propertyName ?? "");
    }
}

// this is connected to the DispatherTimer
private void TimerCallback(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    List<string> changes = null;
    lock (_propertyChanges) {
        _Timer.Stop(); // doing this in callback is safe and disables timer
        if (!_propertyChanges.Contain(""))
            changes = new List<string>(_propertyChanges);
        _propertyChanges.Clear();
    }
    if (changes == null)
        OnPropertyChange(null);
    else
        foreach (string property in changes)
            OnPropertyChanged(property);
}
```

Comment: Hmm, well, at least your solution seems generic enough to reuse.   What would you say the drawbacks to this method are (besides the locking)?

Comment: I have used the solution in many applications without drawbacks. The tricky part is to find a timer interval that avoids "jumpy" updates in scrolling lists etc. The lock is taken so rarely that it shouldn't be a problem. Specially compared to the thread switch which normally happens on every PropertyChange event.

Comment: Thank you very much for the code. This in a way proves my complain against WPF -- why to use such proxy every time you databind, when it could be built in WPF itself. This way you could always databind without worrying if you jam the channel which WPF listens to.

Comment: Each output system got defaults. This applies to simple things like value formatting and more complicated stuff like databinding updates. Sometimes the defaults work with your model and sometimes they don't. If the defaults don't work you add a proxy (and call it ViewModel, controller etc). I think WPF has the right default in this case. For some GUI it might be important that the GUI receives every event which would be very difficult to implement if it wasn't the default.

Comment: a) The default should be an option -- update always, per 1 sec, per 2 seconds, etc. b) The problem is not that WPF receives everything, the problem is if WPF is aware of receiving something, it will listen to **everything**.

Answer (score 4):

This isn't really a WPF issue per se.  When you have a long-running operation that updates a set of data rapidly, keeping the UI updated - any UI, whether it's WPF or WinForms or just VT100 emulation - is going to present the same problem.  UI updates are comparatively slow and complex, and integrating them with a fast-changing complex process without hurting that process requires a clean separation between the two.

That clean separation is even more important in WPF because the UI and the long-running operation need to run on separate threads so that the UI doesn't freeze while the operation is running.

How do you achieve that clean separation?  By implementing them independently, providing a mechanism for periodically updating the UI from within the long-running process, and then testing everything to figure out how frequently that mechanism should be invoked.

In WPF, you'll have three components:  1) a view, which is the physical model of your UI, 2) a view model, which is the logical model of the data that is displayed in the UI, and that pushes changes in the data out to the UI through change notification, and 3) your long-running process.

The long-running process can be almost completely unaware of the UI, so long as it does two things.  It needs to expose public properties and/or methods so that the view model can examine its state, and it needs to raise an event whenever the UI should be updated.

The view model listens to that event.  When the event is raised, it copies state information from the process to its data model, and its built-in change notification pushes those out to the UI.

Multithreading complicates this, but only a bit.  The process needs to run on a different thread than the UI, and when its progress-reporting event is handled, its data will be copied across threads.

Once you've built these three pieces, the multithreading is very straightforward to accomplish using WPF's `BackgroundWorker`.  You create the object that's going to run the process, wire its progress-reporting event up with the `BackgroundWorker`'s `ReportProgress` event, and marshal data from the object's properties to the view model in that event handler.  Then fire off the object's long-running method in the `BackgroundWorker`'s `DoWork` event handler and you're good to go.

Comment: BackgroundWorker does not help (see previous question). About GUIs comparison -- in normal GUI I would bind to the source (like Counter) not entire class. This means I would be notified when Counter changes, not when **something** changes (and then WPF has to check if it was Counter). I disagree that 3-layer design is better than 2-layer -- you design the middle layer similarly from project to project. This means, it should be incorporated to WPF itself to avoid repetitions, i.e. WPF databinding mechanism should update display **periodically** not in greedy mode (or has option to set mode).

Comment: I can tell you that the approach I've outlined works well.  I don't see anything in what you've posted that would contradict this.  I also *strongly* disagree that "you design the middle layer similarly from project to project."  There are some common elements of VM design, yes, but not as many as you seem to think.  Finally, data binding only updates when the VM raises `ProgressChanged`.  You can have as much control over when that happens as you want to exert.

Comment: Well, I know it works well. But when you look at the cost of such solution, it is a killer. Each time you would like to display something, you have to duplicate it -- I would say it is OK, unless I didn't know there are better GUIs or designs. It is like comparing bubble sort and quick sort -- both work, but the amount of work...

Comment: By "duplicate it," you mean "copy its value from a structure owned by the background thread to a structure owned by the foreground thread"?  Yes, that's a cost of multi-threading.  Multi-threading is the cost of having a responsive UI while a long-running operation is in progress.  What alternative would you suggest?

Comment: Not really a value, but a notifier which slows down notifications. Probably I am alone here, but for me it is odd WPF does not prevent jamming -- it was known problem in advance, and the solution was also know in advance. Once done in one place would save us writing the same code. I am all for -- clever design, write once and forget.

Comment: Me too:  that's why I've built this into my view model base class.

Answer (score 3):

A user interface that changes faster than the human eye can observe (~25 updates/sec) is not a usable user interface.  A typical user will observe the spectacle for at most a minute before giving up completely.  You are well past this if you made the UI thread freeze.

You have to design for a human, not a machine.

Comment: Who told you the UI is updated that fast? UI can change per 1 hour, and it will be frozen nevertheless.

Comment: @macias - somebody that said that Sleep(1) solved the problem.  Hey, wasn't that you?

Comment: Yes, that was me, and this proves something? The fact GUI updates (or not) is something different than **listening**. WPF can be jammed by just this -- listening.

Answer (score 1):

Since there are too many notifications for the UI to handle, why not just throttle the notifications a bit? This seems to work fine:

```
        if (value % 500 == 0)
            OnPropertyChanged("Counter");
```

You could also limit the frequency of the notifications, using a timer:

```
    public SO4522583()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _timer = new DispatcherTimer();
        _timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(50);
        _timer.Tick += new EventHandler(_timer_Tick);
        _timer.Start();
        DataContext = this;
    }

    private bool _notified = false;
    private DispatcherTimer _timer;
    void _timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _notified = false;
    }

    ...

    long counter;
    public long Counter
    {
        get { return counter; }
        set
        {
            if (counter != value)
            {
                counter = value;
                if (!_notified)
                {
                    _notified = true;
                    OnPropertyChanged("Counter");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

---

EDIT: if you cannot afford to skip notifications because they're used by other parts of your code, here's a solution that doesn't require big changes in your code:

- create a new property `UICounter`, which throttles the notifications as shown above
- in the `Counter` setter, update `UICounter`
- in your UI, bind to `UICounter` rather than `Counter`

Comment: Those are a no-go solutions -- you forget that notifications are essential part of the program workflow. Skipping notifications is simply ignoring some data in processing, I could skip some at the GUI side, but not in general -- and I cannot filter out where they go (who is receiver) because of design of WPF (single channel of transmission).

Comment: Well, it depends... if you're using a pattern like MVVM, the property in the ViewModel is there only to be displayed in the UI, so it should not be an issue. If you're binding the UI directly to the business components, perhaps you should consider a change in your architecture.

Comment: Thomas, thank you, I will add it to workarounds in a second. The issue here, I don't design a library for WPF, if I did, I wouldn't make it a library -- it is multipurpose library. And duplicating every object that sends notification just because it can be databinded by WPF has serious negative impact on the design of the library and on all non-WPF frontends. Oh, EDIT: this won't work -- either you skip some changes, or you will jam receiver too.

Comment: @macias: "I don't design a library for WPF" => But you need to use it in WPF. That's typically the type of scenario where you would greatly benefit from using the MVVM pattern. The Model would be your current business code, the ViewModel would expose the model to the view and perform all necessary adaptations (such as keeping refresh frequency at a reasonable level), and the View would bind to the ViewModel

Comment: Oh, so you are proposing not to duplicate the data inside the library, but to create the 3rd layer, which would duplicate all the library objects, just so the WPF could breathe? Ok, it will work, but the amount of time spent of creating all the proxies can be hardly justified -- anyway thanks for sharing. Added to workarounds!

Comment: Well, it's true that it will take some time to implement the ViewModel layer, but if you want to make a library that is UI-agnostic, it's probably your best option. Keep the model in your library, and put the ViewModel in your WPF app (or a separate assembly if you prefer)

Comment: This is slightly incorrect -- the proxy is not in the library, but with front-end. For me, it is an example of design overkill (this is not against you, rather WPF designers) -- think about it, with normal GUI toolkit, you design front-end and that's it, with WPF you have to design a frontend AND a proxy which one task only, is to hide the limitations of the frontend. How weird is it? ;-)

Answer (score 0):

A layer between UI and the library is necessary. This will ensure that you will be able to do interaction testing and also allow you to swap out the library with another implementation in future without much change. This isn't a duplication, but a way of providing an interface for UI layer to communicate. This layer will accept objects from library, convert them to specific data transfer objects and pass them onto another layer which will have the responsibility to throttle the updates and convert them to your specific VM objects. 
My opinion is that VMs should be as dumb as possible and their only responsibility should be to provide data to views.

Answer (score 0):

Your qestion sounds similar to [slow-down-refresh-rate-of-bound-datagrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4448916/slow-down-refresh-rate-of-bound-datagrid). 
At least the answers are similar

- Have a shadow copy of your data bound to the gui element instead of binding the original data.
- Add an eventhandler that update the shadow-copy with a certain delay from the original data.

Answer (score 0):

You need to disconnect the source of the notifications from the target for the notifications.  The way you have it set up now, every time the value changes, you go through an entire refresh cycle (which I believe is blocking your processing function from continuing as well).  This is not what you want.

Provide an Output stream to your processing function which it would use to write its notifications.

On the monitoring side, attach an input stream to that outputstream and use it as the data source for your UI component.  This way there isn't any notification event handling going on at all - the processing is running flat out as fast as it can, outputting monitor data to the output stream you provide.  Your monitor UI is simply rendering whatever it receives in the input stream.

You will need a thread to continuously read from the input stream. If no data is available, then it should block.  If it reads some data, it should dump it into the UI.

Regards,

Rodney